# CSS Bootstrap 4.5.1 Navigation Component not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Note:** Problem is still the same when only the `navbar-header` is there in the markup.

I have this markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap 4 practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Navbar Toggle</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="brand.jpg" alt="BRAND" width="100px"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="sr-only">current</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Only the `brand.jpg` is visible and an empty button besides it. [image: the results]

Even if there is no markup except for the `navbar-header`, the results are still the same. What is something that I am missing? Maybe the bootstrap version issue?

I'm using Opera Stable 73.0.3

Comment: Do the development tools (network tab) show the CSS is loading?

Comment: @Gerard Yes!, all the markup and css are included. Thats why I was thinking maybe any version update changed a name or so because I recently saw that `col-[ss]-offset-n` is no more functional instead `offset-n` works.

Comment: I am unable to figure out why there are two lists in `nav`. What are you trying to achieve? Refer to this [guide for creating a simple navbar using bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/).

Comment: @ankitbeniwal for me there is nothing to achieve as such. I am following a bootstrap book and more or less the markup matches it. As I said, even if there is no markup except for `navbar-header div`, the results are same. There should be a hamburger as far as I have learnt.

Comment: When I run your code using <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> it looks much better already.

Comment: @Gerard the problem is of version. I have tried various versions of bootstrap. My markup works perfect on bootstrap v3 but fails on v4. If anyone has been using bootstrap v4 they would be great help as I am 100% sure that only class names have been changed a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using Bootstrap-3 codes in bootstrap-4 version. If you want to use Bootstrap-3, you have to download Bootstrap-3. If you use Bootstrap-3 CDN, you have to include **jquery-3.5.1** and **bootstrap-3.4.1/js** at the bottom of your HTML code (before the closing body tag). Check my code below. Here I have used CDN.

**Bootstrap - 3:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap 4 practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Navbar Toggle</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="BRAND" width="50px"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Or if you want to use Bootstrap-4, use Bootstrap-4 codes.

**Bootstrap - 4:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="BRAND" width="50px"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
          </ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">link</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
      </nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `dropdowns` don't work in desktop mode but works 100% in mobile view. I could not find why so.

Comment: Here I can see both dropdowns are working. Check the snippet I have attached. Maybe you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. There were a few conflicting styles causing the problem.